# python, numpy: force new arrays to be as type float

Tags: python, numpy

Every now and then I wrote code like this:

```
import numpy as np   
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a[1]=3.3
a[2] *= 50
print(a)
```

Here I do not inted `a` to be initalized as `int`, but as `float`, but as I said I forget it.

Now is there a way to make sure such initializations default to float, unless dtype is explicitly specified?

Answer (score 9):

Not without changing the source, no. Your options are:

Get in the habit of putting dots at the end of your numbers:

```
np.array([1.,2.,3.])
```

Use `dtype` explicitly:

```
np.array([1,2,3], dtype=float)
```

Make a new function:

```
def ozi_array(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'dtype' not in kwargs:
        return np.array(*args, dtype=float, **kwargs)
    return np.array(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `dtype` parameter see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Comment: I think the question is how to change the default `dtype=None` to `dtype=float`.

Comment: Adding a wrapper function... you can't change `np` dtype:

`>>> np.dtype='float'
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3])
array([1, 2, 3])`